# Google Play games Services, SHA1 which key to add for public version?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console

I had released my android game, with Google Play games Services, and the SHA1 certificate is correct. App signing certificate SHA1 key should be used right?
The testers are able to login, but publicly the users are unable to do so. It's being 2 days after publishing, and still it is not working for public.
Can someone help me out why?

Comment: How you get that `sha1`?. Do you get it from signingReport?

Comment: Play console > app release > app signing > app signing certificate > SHA1 certificate

Answer (score 0):

use SHA1 Certificate key from play store console
Reference link:
https://prnt.sc/rao0sm

Comment: I did used this, but it's 2 days, and still the public users are unable to login.  Testers were perfectly using the service.

Comment: Any suggestions why it is not working for public users, after publishing?

Comment: Please show this link:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#avoiding_common_setup_problems

Comment: Thank you so much, I had published the app update first, then play games services, what can I do to improve, any idea?